# Convert Dict to dict with children and "unlimited" depth

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, children

I'm trying to convert dict for current view to format that I can use it in AngularJS object:

```
 data = "{'root': {'host': {'hostname1': {'10.0.0.1': {}}, 'hostname2': {'10.0.0.2': {}}}, 'monitor': {'bandwidth': {'hostname1': {'10.0.0.1': {'hostname1': {'10.0.0.1': {'10': {}}}, 'hostname2': {'10.0.0.2': {'10': {}}}}}, 'hostname2': {'10.0.0.2': {'hostname1': {'10.0.0.1': {'10': {}}}, 'hostname2': {'10.0.0.2': {'10': {}}}}}}}}}"
```

to format with names and children values, like:

```
[{
    name: "Node 1",
    children: [{
        name: "Node 1.1",
        children:[{name:"Node 1.1.1"},{name: "Node 1.1.2"}]
    }]},{
    name: "Node 2",
    children: [{name: "Node 2.1"},{name: "Node 2.2"}]
}]
```

I tried few different approaches, but always received partial results. For example I tried to use recursion, it went till the depth value and then ignored all other tree.

```
def modifydict2(data):
for key, value in data.items():
    return [{'name': key, 'children':modifydict2(value)}]
```

As a result I received only part of my dict back. I understood that my loop never worked cause I returned value before next iteration, but not sure how to fix that:

```
[{'name': 'root', 'children': [{'name': 'host', 'children': [{'name': 'ctest1.prod01.weave.local', 'children': [{'name': '10.32.62.1', 'children': None}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: What is the question? can you clear up the question a little bit? Thanks! @CblpHuK

Answer (score 1):

You need to append those individual values that you're currently returning to a list and then return that list. Or, using a list comprehension:

```
def modify_dict(d):
    return [{'name': key, 'children': modify_dict(value)}
            for key, value in d.items()]
```